# how can i use Google Cloud SDK in local development server in Windows machine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I have already installed Google Cloud SDK in my Windows machine. In the Google Cloud SDK shell, I run the following command,

```
dev_appserver.py c:/helloworld
```

helloworld is the folder containing where app.yaml and helloworld.py. But it's showing the following error

```
raise yaml.errors.eventerrors.......
```

Comment: I've re-tagged this for you. Choosing tags relevant to you problem will help you get assistance faster.

Comment: Can you show us the full output you're seeing? Can you share the app.yaml file?

Comment: Shouldn't `dev_appserver.py` be executed in a **windows** shell instead of the cloud SDK shell?